# Convert any SQL query to case insensitive

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-query-language

So my users will send a query to my server, something like:

```
SELECT * WHERE myTable contains “some text”
```

And then I run that query on their database. 
My users are not tech savvy at all. Even that simple query is confusing to them. So in order to make the search case insensitive I have to do:

```
SELECT * WHERE LOWER(myTable) contains LOWER(“some text”)
```

But I don’t want my users to have to put in LOWER(). They will really get overwhelmed (they aren’t programmers!)

The other problem is, I allow them to do other queries like:

```
WHERE myTable2 > 5
WHERE order by myTable
WHERE myTable3 matches “text”
```

Is there a way for me to transform those contains searches to be case insensitive without having my users put in `LOWER()` ?

Comment: An answer depends on which sql database you use.

Comment: There is a `FROM` missing in your *queries*

Comment: Please specify what RDBMS (SQL Server; MySQL; Oracle...)  are you using.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. This is actually the google sheets visualization api that I’m using. You can use SQL queries to search google sheets.

Comment: How do the users send the query? How do you receive it? What language do you manipulate the query in before sending it to viz api?

Comment: That's not SQL. That's Google Query Language, which is not the same thing. Your question also has nothing to do with regular expressions. I've removed the non-applicable tags. Please read the description of tags before using them -  they have specific meanings here.